# MySQL monster query optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have this large MySQL query that I developed long time ago. It is far from perfect and now the time has come to optimize it. I don't even know where to start, maybe add indexes to the tables involved? Or break the query down to subqueries, store them as views, and then reassemble the result using those views?
Please tell me how you would handle such task.

Link to the query:
http://pastebin.com/sVvW8PCc

MySQL version used: 5.0.96

It currently loads in like 6,5 seconds, I look to reduce this time to 2 seconds or less.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show the output from EXPLAIN, please.

Comment: Wow - where to start? I'd start by taking out all the subqueries - any reason why you can't just do joins? "LEFT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT d_ticker AS Ticker1, d_priceprevclose AS P1  FROM table_d  WHERE d_updated = (  SELECT MAX( d_updated )  FROM table_d  WHERE d_updated <= (  DATE_SUB( (  SELECT MAX( d_updated )  FROM table_d ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ))))  AS table_d1  ON Ticker = Ticker1" could be "LEFT OUTER JOIN table_d as table_d1 ...".

Comment: EXPLAIN statement on this query is under this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At34xVWtnIMWdHpTMkFfTzUtRi0wX1ZQb3BxX3V1aVE&usp=sharing

Comment: please put your EXPLAIN into pastebin, so we don't have to sign into google.

Comment: @AgRizzo, here's pastebin of the EXPLAIN output: http://pastebin.com/MwaLAC3J

You pretty much answered my question already, though. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have indexes, then do that first.

It looks like you are using the same query in each UNION, just changing the wildcard (In other words, the joins are all the same with only the wildcard being different.)  If so, focus on 1 part of the UNION only (e.g., the WIND) and make sure that is running as efficiently as possible.  You can then duplicate the changes to the others.

I would suspect (if the previous statement is true) that you can combine the UNION queries into one, by using a `CASE` statement in the `SELECT` clause.  (You will need to use a GROUP BY also)

You often determine the MAX(d_updated).  I am not sure if MySQL caches the result of that or tries to determine it every time.  Why not determine that value once before executing this query, then send it back into your query as a hard coded value?

Finally, I would recommend using Views, not for performance, but for readability.

Comment: Just adding the indexes reduced the time from over 6,5 seconds to less than 1 second. Thanks for you answer.